# how to make css :after / :before content clickable on a label element

Tags: css

Hi i have this html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<label for="button2">something here</label>
```

So the idea is when I click on the label, the checkbox is going to be activated. Now if I add this css

```
label:before{
  content:'some content';
...
}
```

of course I know that there is no reason to add that through css but just a simplified example, to help me explain myself.

Now I want to be able to click on 'some content' generated will css and I want it to have the same effect as the label. So when I click on 'some content' the checkbox would be activated. Can that be done

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using Javascript, I think something this MIGHT be somewhat possible, but it surely wouldn't be browser compatible.

Comment: @DylanCross I agree but this is not going to be for any important website - I just wanted to learn about this (A kind of personal tutorial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does work in all browsers (Fx, IE, Opera) for exception of Chrome and Safari. It’s apparently a WebKit-specific bug.

But the bug can be worked around by specifying `display: inline-block` or `display: block` (depending on what is more appropriate in your specific case) for `LABEL`.

Answer (score 1):

To work around this, you could try putting the label content in span inside the label, and apply the `:before` style to the span instead. That way the content added by the `:before` will still be inside the label.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<label for="button2"><span>something here</span></label>


label>span:before{
  content:'some content';
  ...
}
```

Not ideal, as it adds extra markup, but it should do the trick for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Woo Hoo! I already had an element inside the label.  Works great!